# Eclipse showing missing jar when it's there

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have added maven dependency folder in my build path in eclipse but it's showing some jar files are missing whereas they are still there when i browse them from nautilus. i am using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: have you configured your maven project properly ? Or please try to explain more.. if possible with snapshot of directory structure of your project from eclipse.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please explain and show relevant information. Are you using maven in your project?

Answer (score 0):

> I have added maven dependency folder in my build path

You do not add the dependency folder yourself. If you have installed m2e, maven will automatically download dependencies and add them to your classpath.

> but it's showing some jar files are missing

Does it really say "file-version.jar is missing" or like "Class not found"?

> when i browse them from nautilus

So, did you put .jar-files somewhere in your file system manually? If so, you need to use

```
<dependency>
     ...
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>../path/to/dependency.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

But it is generally recommended not to use system-scoped dependencies. Let maven download them, or install your own dependencies locally by using the install target.

Also, make sure you refresh your project. If you have m2e installed, press `[alt]+[F5]` or right-click on your project and selecet `maven -> update project`. This will re-download all needed dependencies and plugins which are specified in your `pom.xml`.